# Kendo chart - zoom ruins the axis values

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-chart

I'm trying to create a scattered chart with Angular-Kendo,
and have some challenges with zooming.
The current challenge is that upon zoom in by area selection with the mouse.
It does the zoom perfectly, besides the fact that it ruins the axis numbers.
I created an example [not angular oriented, but very clear].
[Simple example](https://dojo.telerik.com/@moshic/APUZumug) - you can try to zoom with mouse drag.
Already tried the `[labels]= "{format: '{0: n3}'}"`, etc... but it didn't work...
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found for this very painful item is:
using kendo-chart-x-axis instead of category-axis :-)